# How to chain multiple filters in lazy.js in a loop (from array)

Tags: javascript, typescript, lazy.js

I have an array that contain filter functions that need to be applied to an array of items in Lazy.js. I've tried using a for-loop but only the last filter is applied.

```
function (searchText) {
    var result = Lazy(input);

    for (var query of this.querylist) {
        result = result.filter((item) => {
            return query.filterFunc(item, searchText, query.compareFunc);
        });
    }

    return result.toArray();
}
```

Is there a way of applying a list of filters without hardcoding the chaining?

[Here is a fiddle showing the issue](http://jsfiddle.net/6fu66Lgy/2/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use **reduce** to iterate over the **filters** and create a resulting one by applying each one to the previous one.

```js
var result = Lazy(contentArray);

var allFilters = filters.reduce(function(acc, current) {
    return acc.filter((item) => current.filterFunc(item)); // return the last one with the current filter applied
}, result); // start with the original one


console.log(allFilters.toArray())
```

You can find an updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/eunfqc1t/).

The **reduce** is just a nicer and more generic way of this:

```js
var allFilters = result
                  .filter(filters[0])
                  .filter(filters[1])
                  .filter(filters[2]);
```

Lazy.js will not call the filters until you call toArray or forEach. I put some logs in [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/dxf13co9/).

Comment: does reduce() resolve partly, or is query resolution deferred until allFilters.toArray() is called. Does it still have significant performance gains compared to lodash or underscore?

Comment: all reduce does is to create a Lazy array that has all the filters in the filters array applied to it. The actual invocation is done when toArray is called. Regarding performance gain.. I have no idea. I never actually tested the performance of those libraries.